# How to pipe each jq filter output to an external command?

Tags: json, pipe, jq

I have a large file with a sequence of `JSON` objects.  Each object has a value that I want to extract and run through an external program.  How do you instruct `jq` to do this?

For example, if I have the following `JSON` file:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "corp": "Slate Rocks",
  "pubKey": "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMFowDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADSQAwRgJBAMBUAZGIzQsPO1PXgjdCJUxcZNc6Y4FY\ncVC+JxZIUfaz0WkLI7H4tiKCsd+2F+3Xf+hObSbdoUi1UuT5uzpsda8CAQM=\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----",
  "update": "2018-12-10"
}
{
  "id": 2,
  "corp": "Pi-ryte",
  "pubKey": "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMFowDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADSQAwRgJBALzXcOJvZz2UFPDJphTm++Ho9t+lkTQf\nxH0nSp7lbfCHL5Y5YbnD7pgbD/e/PGIHt+cch3foOlUyH+b0Ht53ZO0CAQM=\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----",
  "update": "2019-03-14"
}
{
  "id": 3,
  "corp": "Marble Dreams",
  "pubKey": "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMFowDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADSQAwRgJBAN1L9v8ZbpJ1/GMlNOfGFjQhhO2KTKpj\nOfp97CDUdCAQ6wzLjagGKbySC16/MpnAvoPUmYEtTRtbdH/rdMGdvd8CAQM=\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----",
  "update": "2018-12-17"
}
```

and I want to output the RSA public key moduli, I need to execute `openssl` for each `"pubKey"` value.

This only works for the first `"pubKey"`:

```sh
$ jq -r '.pubKey' seq.json | openssl rsa -pubin -noout -modulus
Modulus=C054019188CD0B0F3B53D7823742254C5C64D73A6381587150BE27164851F6B3D1690B23B1F8B62282B1DFB617EDD77FE84E6D26DDA148B552E4F9BB3A6C75AF
```

Is there something like:

```sh
$ jq -r '.pubKey | system("openssl rsa -pubin -noout -modulus")' seq.json
```

or

```sh
$ jq -r '.pubKey as $pk | system("openssl rsa -pubin -noout -modulus -in $pk")' seq.json
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An implementation that's careful not to execute data as code might look like:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' chunk; do
  openssl rsa -pubin -noout -modulus <<<"$chunk"
done < <(jq -j '(.pubKey, "\u0000")' seq.json)
```

- The `while read` idiom is documented in detail in [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)
- The use of [process substitution](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst) (the `<(...)` syntax) is for reasons described in [BashFAQ #24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).
- The use of the `-d` argument to `read`, the `-j` argument to `jq`, and the use of `"\u0000"` inside the JSON uses NUL delimiters to separate extracted data items. These are used because NULs are the only character which can't be represented inside C strings; thus, they can be used to represent delimiters between any data item which a C program can store in a string. See [stedolan/jq#1271](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/1271) for history behind this feature in jq.

Comment: Amazing!  That's some serious ***bash-fu*** there!

Comment: What are the parentheses for in the `jq` filter?

Comment: The parens aren't really important here -- what's important is the comma, generating a sequence (XQuery terminology, not jq terminology, but they behave conceptually identically here), such that jq emits first the content behind `.pubQuery`, then emits the literal NUL; since we're using `-j`, there's no delimiter between those two (or any other) items. I personally find that the parens make such sequences easier to read by delimiting their bounds, but it's preference, not necessity.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than doing this within jq, as [jq cannot use program as filter yet](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/1614), you can do it outside it:

```
jq -j --slurp 'map(.pubKey) | join(">")' seq.json | xargs --delimiter=> -n1 --no-run-if-empty -i sh -c 'echo "{}" | openssl rsa -pubin -noout -modulus'
```

Notes:

1. Your sample input is multiple object instead of an array of objects, so `--slurp` is used. If it is not the case you will need to remove this flag.
2. `pubKey` cannot have '>' in it, so I used it as an delimiter. This assumes your data comes from trusty source and won't blow your system up.

Comment: `sh -c '...{}...'` runs major security risks. What if your JSON has `$(rm -rf ~)` inside the string being extracted?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy if pubKey is not trust worthy then using `>` as delimiter is impossible either way. I start off assuming data is safe.

Comment: "Impossible"? You might need to worry about items injecting extra delimiters, but that doesn't raise to the level of welcoming injection attacks.

Comment: To start off assuming data is safe is unwise -- the number of developers who make comparable assumptions are a big part of why my industry (malware analysis) exists. Follow safe practices even when you *think* you're writing something that isn't exposed attack surface, and then you don't get to be proven wrong when systems interact in unexpected ways.

Comment: (BTW, in discussions of trustworthiness, I like using the NSA definition: A "trusted" component is one that can compromise your system if it fails alone, without any other components failing in tandem. Thinking in these terms makes it obvious why trusting things -- whether those things are data values, subsystems, or the like -- is harmful)

Comment: I agree. TBH this is something I had never deal with. My experience on bash mostly involves interacting with trusty data source (local db, local test site, etc). To me, shell is only for makeshift solutions or there is no python whatsoever. If data is not trusty (e.g. crawler output) I tend to switch to python and start mangling with it in a more familiar environment.

Comment: (Incidentally, I consider the `system()` function in awk an antipattern, and have opened a discussion in the ticket you linked about how `jq` can and should do it better, if implementing something similar in the future).